# Calculate discrete log with known phi

Tags: discrete-logarithm

Is it possible to efficiently solve the discrete log problem for $r$:
$$
g^r\equiv v\pmod N
$$
When the following constants are know:
$$
N,\ g,\ v,\ \phi=(p-1)(q-1)\text{ s.t. }N=p\,q
$$

Comment: Closely [related question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/52176/555)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as we know, no, there is no general method to efficiently solve the Discrete Logarithm Problem for composite $N$ even when $\phi(N)$ is given and $N$ is the product of two distinct primes†. Argument: make $p$ any large prime with $(p-1)/2$ prime such as [this](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3526#section-5), $q=3$, $N\gets p\,q$, $\phi\gets2(p-1)$, $g=2$, and $v$ computed as $g^r\bmod N$ for $r$ a random integer the size of $(p-1)/2$. Ability to solve the DLP modulo $N$ implies ability to solve it modulo $p$, which is widely believed hard.

The best method we have goes:

- First factor $N$, which is possible from $N$ and $\phi$, see e.g. [this](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/62487/555).
- Reduce the original problem to two DLPs modulo $p$ and $q$ using the [Chinese Remainder Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem). For some rare values of $g$ and $v$ that may allow to conclude there can't be a solution, or exhibit solution(s).
- Try to factor $p-1$ and $q-1$.
- Apply the [Pohlig-Hellman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pohlig%E2%80%93Hellman_algorithm) algorithm, which when $(p-1)/2$ and $(q-1)/2$ are not prime and have known factors will reduce each of the two DLPs to several simpler ones, that we perhaps can solve using the [function field sieve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_field_sieve), [index calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Index_calculus_algorithm), [Pollard's kangaroo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pollard%27s_kangaroo_algorithm) or [Pollard's rho](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pollard%27s_rho_algorithm_for_logarithms).

---

† The question's equation $\phi=(p-1)(q-1)$ is equivalent to $p$ and $q$ being distinct primes when we restrict to strictly positive $p$ and $q$; see [there](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4609823/35016).